# Device used by teens to transform

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

It was around 2008 to 2010. A team of kids has a device to transform with one button. The main character has a brown colored one. The team has more than 4 members. One character transforms into a hero with closed eyes and has wings. When they are transforming, camera tapes will come out.

The series takes place in space for the most part. In one episode, one of the main characters cries, one teardrop falls on a device, causing the hero of that device to come out. In another episode, the villain pushes one of the heroes towards a planet and the planet gets destroyed.

What cartoon is this?

Comment: What are camera tapes?

Comment: Like camera reels that they used to put in old cameras.

Comment: Cartoon or live action? Are the transformed forms still human sized? Planet sized? It varies?

Comment: It's an action series, transformed character forms like like human size

Answer (score 7):

This sounds like it could be [Digimon Frontier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digimon_Frontier).

> It was around 2008 to 2010.

Digimon Frontier aired from 2002 - 2003, so you may have just watched it later

> A team of kids has a device to transform with one button

The team of kids (Digidestined) use a device called the [D-Tector](https://digimon.fandom.com/wiki/Digivice#D-Tector) to transform into Spirit Digimon

> The main character has a brown colored one

The [main character](https://digimon.fandom.com/wiki/Takuya_Kanbara) has a combination of red, black, and brown in its various forms. The base form is primarily redish/brownish

[image: Flamemon]

> The team has more than 4 members.

Digimon Frontier contains a team of 5 members

> One character transforms into a hero with closed eyes and has wings

One of the characters can transform into [Kazemon](https://digimon.fandom.com/wiki/Kazemon)

[image: Kazemon]

> When they are transforming, camera tapes will come out.

When the main characters are [Spirit Digivolving](https://youtu.be/HCoXKrBAFKg?t=11), the animation shows a film-like ribbon surrounding their bodies

[image: Spirit Digivolving]

> The series mostly takes in space.

The Digital world in Digimon Frontier is surrounded by three moons, and at some point in the series, they are shown traveling to the various moons.

> the villain pushes one of the heroes towards a planet and the planet gets destroyed.

In one of the episodes, the DigiDestined are fighting one of the primary antagonists on one of the Digital World's moons. [During this fight](https://youtu.be/-mjSB9f97hQ?t=15), the antagonist kicks one of the digimon into the air, and then smashes them into the moon. The moon begins to crack, and then the antagonist destroys it soon after